# Deep copy of the Object to add a key : value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-query

I am pre-fetching a product from a database using `mongoose` with `next.js` and `react-query`. I was wondering why I need to do a deep copy of a nested object in order to add a key:value to it. Otherwise it does not work. Let me know what I am not understanding.

```
await queryClient.prefetchQuery(['productSlug', slug], async () => {
  const product = await read(slug);

  const existingRatingObject = product.ratings.find(
    (item) => item.postedBy.toString() === user._id.toString()
  );
  const copyProduct = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(product));

  if (existingRatingObject) {
    copyProduct.star = existingRatingObject.star;
  } else {
    copyProduct.star = 0;
  }

  console.log({ copyProduct });
  return JSON.stringify(copyProduct);
});
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to do that? What does "it does not work" mean exactly?

Comment: When I am trying to add a new key:value without a deep copy it does not work. I am not sure why.

Comment: **What does "it does not work" mean?** What happens? Anything? Is an error reported?

Comment: nothing happens. no error. no new key : value added to the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that the product fetched is a Mongoose document not a plain old JavaScript object.

When you convert it to plain old javascript Object, you will be able to add any key to it.

You can add .lean() to you query or add toObject/toJSON to you the fetched document